# Which is more advisable for simple kernel development- Docker or VM?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am getting started with OS concepts and I have few programming assignments on editing and loading kernel modules. If I use Docker Images ( Ubuntu/Fedora etc.), will it affect my host OS? I heard that Docker runs on the host OS as compared to VMs which can run separate guest OSs.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about Docker and / or kernel modules? Your question as it stands is a little too broad and is difficult to answer.

Comment: I asked for any downsides of using Docker vs. VMWare for kernel programming ( and not for any app containerisation ) . Host OS = MacOS Guest OS = Debian

Comment: I understand. But those kind of questions are too broad for Stack Overflow and generally not allowed. No one can really answer it and it will be mostly the opinion of the answerer. Docker may be better for one person and VMware for another.

Answer (score 0):

For Kernel development you need to us a virtual machine which sits above a hyper-visor and run the entire guest operating system. Docker images are not actually running the OS, its just virtualising the upper layers of the OS.